# Execute php file from js more times

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

In javascript I have a code which execute php function:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.onload = function getData() {
 var result = this.responseText;
 result = JSON.parse(result);
 console.log(result);
};

oReq.open("get", "../my_php/index.php", true);

const startIt = () => {
 oReq.send();
};
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="startIt()" type="button" >Run</button>
```

This code works fine, but only one time and then the website needs to be refreshed. Otherwise it shows an error:

*InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state.*

Comment: Move everything in to your function.

Comment: Oh, thanks. It works now without any problem

Comment: The code is actually fine, except you need to open the request every time you're going to use it. Hence just moving the line `oReq.open("get", "../my_php/index.php", true);` into the function makes the further requests to work. Recreating XHR object is not mandatory, the original object and its load listener can be reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your helpful comments

I moved `oReq.open("get", "../my_php/index.php", true);` to the function `startIt` and everything works

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.onload = function getData() {
 var result = this.responseText;
 result = JSON.parse(result);
 console.log(result);
};


const startIt = () => {
 oReq.open("get", "../my_php/index.php", true);
 oReq.send();
};
```